# Mixing autosubscribe and messagepoint mappings

Tags: nservicebus5

We have just finished a set of services that use unobtrusive mode to find commands and events (possibly important not messages)

```
conventions.DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.Namespace != null &&    t.Namespace.EndsWith("Commands"));
 conventions.DefiningEventsAs(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith("Events"));
 conventions.DefiningTimeToBeReceivedAs(
            t => t.Name.EndsWith("Expires") ? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) : TimeSpan.MaxValue);
```

There is an existing gateway that is a webapi we use to connect with and it publishes based on the message type it was sent based on `MessageEndpointMappings`. I was expecting the subcriptions table to include entries for the events after installtion. Parameters to /install included

```
/serviceName: 
/displayName: 
/description: 
/endpointConfigurationType: (for services not the saga) 
/username: 
/password:
& NServiceBus.Production
```

The gateway is sent the new event type and makes it to the publish call but it is not picked up by the services. I think the gateway is not able to publish because it does not know about the new type. Do I need to add a `MessageEndpointMappings` to the gateway config or should it be converted to unobtrusive mode. I think mappings will require a reference that it doesn't have anyway and I am not sure if the two methods are compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer to this one. the existing gateway has different schemas and is conflicting the configuration.